# Error: error getting endorser client for channel: endorser client failed to connect to localhost: context deadline exceeded

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

I am working on hyperledger fabric. I wanted to create a new peer first and then create a channel across the new and the existing peer. I want this to happen dynamically in my project. but I am not able to make peer join the channel. This is my first project in hyperledger fabric. please let me know where I am going wrong.( But orderer is joining the channel but peer is not). I am using TLS in this project

This is the error I am getting in my terminal
[image]

Below is the logs from peer and orderer

```
this is my createChannel.sh file
#!/bin/bash

# imports  
. scripts/envVar.sh
. scripts/utils.sh

CHANNEL_NAME="$1"
DELAY="$2"
MAX_RETRY="$3"
VERBOSE="$4"

: ${CHANNEL_NAME:="patdoc-channel${PEER_PATIENT_NUMBER}"}
: ${DELAY:="6"}
: ${MAX_RETRY:="5"}
: ${VERBOSE:="true"}

: ${CONTAINER_CLI:="docker"}
: ${CONTAINER_CLI_COMPOSE:="${CONTAINER_CLI} compose"}

infoln "Using ${CONTAINER_CLI} and ${CONTAINER_CLI_COMPOSE}"

if [ ! -d "channel-artifacts" ]; then
    mkdir channel-artifacts
fi

createChannelGenesisBlock() {
    which configtxgen
    if [ "$?" -ne 0 ]; then
        fatalln "configtxgen tool not found."
    fi
    set -x
    configtxgen -profile TwoOrgsApplicationGenesis -outputBlock ./channel-artifacts/${CHANNEL_NAME}.block -channelID $CHANNEL_NAME
    res=$?
    { set +x; } 2>/dev/null
  verifyResult $res "Failed to generate channel configuration transaction..."
}

createChannel() {
    setGlobals0 "patorg"
    local rc=1
    local COUNTER=1
    while [ $rc -ne 0 -a $COUNTER -lt $MAX_RETRY ] ; do
        sleep $DELAY
        set -x
        osnadmin channel join --channelID $CHANNEL_NAME --config-block ./channel-artifacts/${CHANNEL_NAME}.block -o localhost:7153 --ca-file "$ORDERER_CA" --client-cert "$ORDERER_ADMIN_TLS_SIGN_CERT" --client-key "$ORDERER_ADMIN_TLS_PRIVATE_KEY" >&log.txt
        res=$?
        { set +x; } 2>/dev/null
        let rc=$res
        COUNTER=$(expr $COUNTER + 1)
    done
    cat log.txt
    verifyResult $res "Channel creation failed"
}

# joinChannel ORG
joinChannel() {
    FABRIC_CFG_PATH=$PWD/../config/
    ORG=$1
    PEERNAME=$2
    infoln "Joining PEER${PEERNAME} to Channel ${CHANNEL_NAME}"
    setGlobals0 $ORG
    local rc=1
    local COUNTER=1
    ## Sometimes Join takes time, hence retry
    while [ $rc -ne 0 -a $COUNTER -lt $MAX_RETRY ] ; do
    sleep $DELAY
    set -x
    peer channel join -b $BLOCKFILE>&log.txt
    res=$?
    { set +x; } 2>/dev/null
        let rc=$res
        COUNTER=$(expr $COUNTER + 1)
    done
    cat log.txt
    verifyResult $res "After $MAX_RETRY attempts, peer${PEERNAME}.${ORG} has failed to join channel '$CHANNEL_NAME' "
}

joinChannelDoctor() {
    FABRIC_CFG_PATH=$PWD/../config/
    ORG=$1
    PEERNAME=$2
    infoln "Joining DOCTOR${PEERNAME} to Channel ${CHANNEL_NAME}"
    setGlobals${PEERNAME} $ORG
    local rc=1
    local COUNTER=1
    ## Sometimes Join takes time, hence retry
    while [ $rc -ne 0 -a $COUNTER -lt $MAX_RETRY ] ; do
    sleep $DELAY
    set -x
    peer channel join -b $BLOCKFILE >&log.txt
    res=$?
    { set +x; } 2>/dev/null
        let rc=$res
        COUNTER=$(expr $COUNTER + 1)
    done
    cat log.txt
    verifyResult $res "After $MAX_RETRY attempts, peer${PEERNAME}.${ORG} has failed to join channel '$CHANNEL_NAME' "
}

setAnchorPeer() {
  ORG=$1
  ${CONTAINER_CLI} exec cli ./scripts/setAnchorPeer.sh $ORG $CHANNEL_NAME 
}

FABRIC_CFG_PATH=${PWD}/configtx

## Create channel genesis block
infoln "Generating channel genesis block '${CHANNEL_NAME}.block'"
createChannelGenesisBlock

FABRIC_CFG_PATH=$PWD/../config/
BLOCKFILE="./channel-artifacts/${CHANNEL_NAME}.block"

## Create channel
infoln "Creating channel ${CHANNEL_NAME}"
createChannel
successln "Channel '$CHANNEL_NAME' created"

## Join all the peers to the channel
infoln "Joining patient peer${PEER_PATIENT_NUMBER}  to the channel..."
joinChannel "patorg" ${PEER_PATIENT_NUMBER}

# infoln "Joining doctor peer to the channel ..."
# joinChannelDoctor "docorg" 0

## Set the anchor peers for each org in the channel
# infoln "Setting anchor peer for patorg..."
# setAnchorPeer "patorg" 

successln "Channel '$CHANNEL_NAME' joined"
```

and this is my envVar.sh file

```
#!/bin/bash



# imports
. scripts/utils.sh

# network/

# ENV VARIABLES
export CORE_PEER_TLS_ENABLED=true
export DOCORG_PWD=../../../DoctorNodeCreater/network
export PEER0_PATORG_CA=${PWD}/organizations/peerOrganizations/patorg.patient.com/tlsca/tlsca.patorg.patient.com-cert.pem
export PEER0_DOCORG_CA=${DOCORG_PWD}/organizations/peerOrganizations/docorg.doctor.com/tlsca/tlsca.docorg.doctor.com-cert.pem

export ORDERER_CA=${PWD}/organizations/ordererOrganizations/patient.com/tlsca/tlsca.patient.com-cert.pem
export ORDERER_ADMIN_TLS_SIGN_CERT=${PWD}/organizations/ordererOrganizations/patient.com/orderers/orderer.patient.com/tls/server.crt
export ORDERER_ADMIN_TLS_PRIVATE_KEY=${PWD}/organizations/ordererOrganizations/patient.com/orderers/orderer.patient.com/tls/server.key

export PEER_CA=${PWD}/organizations/peerOrganizations/patorg.patient.com/tlsca/tlsca.patorg.patient.com-cert.pem
export PEER_ADMIN_TLS_SIGN_CERT=${PWD}/organizations/peerOrganizations/patorg.patient.com/peers/peer${PEER_PATIENT_NUMBER}.patorg.patient.com/tls/server.crt
export PEER_ADMIN_TLS_PRIVATE_KEY=${PWD}/organizations/peerOrganizations/patorg.patient.com/peers/peer${PEER_PATIENT_NUMBER}.patorg.patient.com/tls/server.key

# Set environment variables for the peer org
setGlobals0() {
  local USING_ORG=""
  if [ -z "$OVERRIDE_ORG" ]; then
    USING_ORG=$1
  else
    USING_ORG="${OVERRIDE_ORG}"
  fi
  infoln "Using organization ${USING_ORG}"
  if [ $USING_ORG = "patorg" ]; then
    export CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID="PatOrgMSP"
    export CORE_PEER_TLS_ROOTCERT_FILE=$PEER0_PATORG_CA
    export CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=${PWD}/organizations/peerOrganizations/patorg.patient.com/users/Admin@patorg.patient.com/msp
    export CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=localhost:${PEER_PATIENT_PORT}
  elif [ $USING_ORG = "docorg" ]; then
    export CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID="DocOrgMSP"
    export CORE_PEER_TLS_ROOTCERT_FILE=$PEER0_DOCORG_CA
    export CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=${DOCORG_PWD}/organizations/peerOrganizations/docorg.doctor.com/users/Admin@docorg.doctor.com/msp
    export CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=localhost:${PEER_DOCTOR_PORT}  
  else
    errorln "ORG Unknown"
  fi

  if [ "$VERBOSE" == "true" ]; then
    env | grep CORE
  fi
}

setGlobalsCLI0() {
  setGlobals0 $1

  local USING_ORG=""
  if [ -z "$OVERRIDE_ORG" ]; then
    USING_ORG=$1
  else
    USING_ORG="${OVERRIDE_ORG}"
  fi
  if [ $USING_ORG = "patorg" ]; then
    export CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer${PEER_PATIENT_NUMBER}.patorg.patient.com:${PEER_PATIENT_PORT}
  else
    errorln "ORG Unknown"
  fi
}


verifyResult() {
  if [ $1 -ne 0 ]; then
    fatalln "$2"
  fi
}
```

I tried with enabling the tls flag along with giving certfile,keyfile,cafile parameter in peer join but it didn't work

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551). The error messages are text, and can be copied and pasted directly into your question.